# Where should I call initialization code in Phoenix, which might involve connection to a db?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, erlang-otp

I have some code which I need to call upon my Elixir Phoneix application startup. Some of the  parts of the code require a request to database to retrieve data that'll be used for initialization.

While I can call normal code -- one which doesn't do any requests to a database -- in

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Endpoint do 
  # [............]

  #
  # some of my init code will go here
  #


  def init(...) do
    # [.........]
  end
end
```

and if I understand correctly, code that does database, HTTP requests or something like that -- something that may take a lot of time -- shouldn't be called from `MyAppWeb.Endpoint`

Is this correct? If so, from where then I should such code that does initialization?

Comment: you should take a look at `ReleaseTasks` from here: https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html

Comment: @Daniel I honestly doubt I follow how release tasks would help here.

Comment: yeah my bad, I wanted to point to config providers: https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-config-providers

Comment: @Daniel config providers are all about static configuration to be _loaded_ and it’s definitely an anti-pattern to execute some code from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, don’t put the code, unrelated to *Phoenix* itself, into its helpers.

Create your own [`GenServer`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html), do whatever you need, and stop it gracefully.

There are three stages of `GenServer` initialization process:

- [`GenServer.start_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#start_link/3)
- [`GenServer.init/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html?#c:init/1)
- [`GenServer.handle_continue/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html?#c:handle_continue/2)

The first one *is executed in the calling process*, two last are callbacks, executed in already started `GenServer` process, `init/1` synchronously and `handle_continue/2` asynchronously.

That said, the common practice to perform a long-running initialization would be:

```rb
defmodule MyInit do
  use GenServer

  @spec start_link(opts :: keyword()) :: GenServer.on_start()
  @doc "Starts the GenServer process"
  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, ..., name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @impl GenServer
  @doc false
  def init(:ok),  do: {:ok, :ok, {:continue, :connect}}

  @impl GenServer
  @doc false
  def handle_continue(:connect, :ok) do
    do_init(...)
    {:stop, :normal, nil}
  end
end
```

And start this process from your supervision tree.

---

If it’s critical for this initialization to complete *before* the endpoints are started, move the call to `do_init` into `init/1` callback and put this `GenServer` *before* the endpoint in the supervision tree.

Comment: should that GenServer be called as `supervisor(MyInit)` or `worker(MyInit)`? or doesn't matter?

Comment: also, from my `MyInit` I'll need to make a call to another GenServer in my app and particularty to `ets`. Are there any nuances?

Comment: `supervisor(MyInit)` / `worker(MyInit)` were deprecated ages ago. `GenServer` exposes `child_spec`, so just put it _into the supervision tree_. `ets` is by no mean a `GenServer`, and no, there are no nuances, just open it and call (be aware that `ets` is owned by the calling process, so if you open it from this `GenServer`, leave it up and running.

Comment: What `into the supervision tree` do you mean? Can you show me the code? In `application.ex` I have `def start(_type, _args) do` with  multiple `supervisors(AAA)` and `worker(MyInit)` in it.

Comment: Yes, there. There are tons of documentation regarding the subject. [`Application`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Application.html#module-the-application-callback-module) and links from there.